# Вызов асинхронного метода по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python-3.5, асинхронность, pyqt5

Нужно реализовать вызов асинхронного метода после нажатия на кнопку QPushButton. На данный момент после нажатия на кнопку мой виджет вылетает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

UPD: Исправил некоторые ошибки, теперь все работает, листинг кода я тоже обновил.

Листинг кода:

```
import asyncio, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton

class Example(QWidget):

 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):        
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 220)

    self.text1 = QTextEdit("Test", self)

    find = QPushButton("Найти",self)
    find.move(300, 0)
    find.clicked.connect(self.Wait)

    self.show()

 def Wait(self):
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.set_())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    loop.close()

 @asyncio.coroutine
 def set_(self):     
    self.text1.setText("1")       
    yield from asyncio.sleep(0)       


if __name__ == '__main__':

 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 ex = Example()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Второй вариант:

```
import asyncio, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton

class Example(QWidget):

 def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()
  self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):        
  self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 220)

  self.text1 = QTextEdit("Test", self)

  find = QPushButton("Найти",self)
  find.move(300, 0)
  find.clicked.connect(self.Wait)

  self.show()

 def Wait(self):
  task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.set_())
  self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  self.loop.run_until_complete(task)
  self.loop.close()

 async def set_(self):
  self.text1.setText("Hello World")
  await asyncio.sleep(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 ex = Example()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```